# How to use zong with asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Zong is a mobile payment company that allows users to make micropayments on the Internet if they have a postpaid mobile phone The payments are charged to their mobile phone bills by the mobile operator. The company was acquired by eBay in 2011. Zong payments are only accepted by online games and social networks, and the service can be used to purchase virtual goods. I referred the site but how can I integrate it with my asp.net website. I created even the merchant account and it is taking longer time to confirm.

Comment: http://www.zong.com/help/merchant is the page where you can see some basic information. Get started by registering to http://www.zong.com/merchants/get-started and you will find more help.

Comment: Are u making a mobile application that will run under a mobile environment or a normal web page which runs under Windows OS and users may access by their mobiles via their mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

Well anish,

I saw your earlier post as well for the ZONG. [How to integrate zong mobile payment service with a asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621496/how-to-integrate-zong-mobile-payment-service-with-a-asp-net-website)

If you see their website they claim the following.

```
How does Zong integrate with my website?

We have a simple HTML iFrame which embeds into or on top of your web page.
```

which means that they do allow you to integrate on web application and websites as well, for asp.net or php that is not matter because they just provide you the iFrame and you can control the look and feel of it.

Again coming back to the question you have that it is taking log time them to confirm your merchant account; what best you can do is that you can contact them and that what is their normal turn around time for merchant account creation.

Hope this helps.