# How to integrate zong mobile payment service with a asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, web, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I referred but I couldn't able to find a suitable answer on how to integrate the zong mobile payment with asp.net website. Can anyone give me a suitable link where we can know how to integrate zong with a website.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.zong.com/help/merchant where they provide some questions and answers. Just register a trial account with them and get started. Once you logged in to the system, you will have much more details.

Comment: @Prasjant Lakhlani I looked into that and registered before for development but they are not replying. They have to give the login id and password for merchant